# Jmeter: what happens when I stop the Script in between?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am running a scenario for 200User in Jmeter.

Login
AddTask
Logout

In between I stopped the Script.
Login(all 200 ran)
Add Task(160Ran)
Logout(80Ran)

All 80 are logged out now. What about the other 120. Are they still Loged in?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the application. Usually, it is like - you login and close your browser. 
Your webserver will destroy the session created in 30mins (as per the config).